# Django query joining two tables

Tags: django, inner-join, django-queryset

I am new in django. I want to create a query in django I tried with `select_related` but I don't know how to insert the second part of the condition: `AND model1.qty >= model2.items`

I've tried:

```
Model1.objects.select_related('model2).filter(model1.qty__gte=?)
```

But it's not working properly.

Below is the SQL query which I want to implement with django queryset:

```
 SELECT model1.name,model2.name WHERE model1.id=model2.model1.id AND model1.qty >= model2.items
```

My models:

```py
class Article(models.Model): 
    date_crea = models.DateTimeField('Créer le', auto_now_add=True)
    designation = models.TextField('designation', max_length=500)
    seuil = models.IntegerField('Seuil d\'alerte')

class Stock(models.Model):
    date_crea = models.DateTimeField('Créer le', auto_now_add=True)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qte_reel = models.IntegerField('stock reel',default=0)
```

Comment: Can you show us your models?

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Please add it into your question.

Comment: Article.objects.filter(seuil__gt = article_set.qte_reel).values('designation', 'article_set__date_crea')

Comment: @JayVasant i try your solution i have got this error NameError: name 'article_set' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use an [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters) to refer to the value of a field in the database. There have to be relations to follow from the current object to the field on the object that you want to compare against.

I'm not clear how the question relates to the posted models, but an F expression can follow a foreign key so

```
Stock.objects.filter( qte_reel__gte = F( 'article__seuil' ))
```

would work, if those fields are the ones you want to compare.